# Loading and saving a class using qsettings

Tags: c++, qt

I have an ini file as shown

```
[Profiles]
hh\Ta=20
hh\Te=48
hh\Texp=38
hh\lim1=0
hh\lim2=0
hh\offset=0
hh\profilename=hh

tt\Ta=20
tt\Te=48
tt\Texp=38
tt\lim1=0
tt\lim2=0
tt\offset=0
tt\profilename=hh
```

I'm trying to load it, but I get all the data as zeros, like Ta Te Texp,..etc

The file is saved correctly but loading the values back is not working.

Is it a problem with setting the group,..etc ?

here is my load and save mechanism

```
void Method::loadFrom(Settings &set, bool ownGroup)
{
    set.beginGroup("Profiles");
    foreach (const QString &group, set.childGroups()) {
        set.beginGroup(group);
        Profile *profile = new Profile();
        profile->setObjectName(group);
        profile->loadFrom(set);
        set.endGroup();

        m_currentProfile->m_Profiles << profile;
    }
    set.endGroup();

    EraObject::staticLoadFrom(set, this, ownGroup);

}

void Method::saveTo(Settings &set, bool ownGroup, bool force)
{
    set.beginGroup("Profiles");
    foreach(Profile * profile, m_currentProfile->m_Profiles) {
        profile->saveTo(set);
        set.endGroup();
    }
    set.sync();

    EraObject::staticSaveTo(set, this, ownGroup, force);

}


class Settings : public QSettings
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit Settings(QString fileName);
    ~Settings();
private:
    Q_DISABLE_COPY(Settings)
};



void EraObject::staticLoadFrom(Settings &set, QObject *object, const bool &ownGroup)
{
    Q_ASSERT(object);
    bool modified;
    const QMetaObject *superMeta = object->metaObject()->superClass();
    const QMetaObject *meta = object->metaObject();

    const QString &group = object->objectName().isEmpty() ? meta->className() : object->objectName();

    if (ownGroup)
        set.beginGroup(group);

    qCDebug(loadLog) << group;

    for (int i = superMeta->propertyOffset(); i < meta->propertyCount(); i++) {
        modified = false;
        const QMetaProperty &prop = meta->property(i);
        QMetaType::Type type = (QMetaType::Type)prop.type();

        if (prop.isUser()) {
            switch (type) {
            case QMetaType::QDateTime:
                modified = setOrReset(set, object, prop, QDateTime::fromString(set.value(prop.name(), "").toString(), "yyyyMMddhhmmsszzz"));
                break;
            case QMetaType::QString: {  //check if there is an localized string first (eg.: name@de=test)
                const QVariant value = set.value(QString("%1@%2").arg(prop.name()).arg(QLocale::system().bcp47Name()),
                                                 set.value(prop.name(), ""));
                modified = setOrReset(set, object, prop, value);
                break;
            }
            case QVariant::UserType: {
                QObject *obj = prop.read(object).value<QObject *>();
                Q_ASSERT_X(obj, "staticLoadFrom", "Custom class NOT known to QMetaType, register it with qmlRegisterType()!");

                bool check = QMetaObject::invokeMethod(obj,
                                                       "loadFrom",
                                                       Qt::DirectConnection,
                                                       Q_ARG(Settings &, set));    //we invoke cause it can be just QObject(e.g. QAbstractItemModel)
                Q_ASSERT_X(check, "staticLoadFrom", "Could not invoke. Be sure you subclassed EraObject or defined method!: " + obj->objectName().toLatin1());
                break;
            }
            default:
                modified = setOrReset(set, object, prop, set.value(prop.name(), ""));
            }

            qCDebug(loadLog) << "modified:" << modified << "Property:" << prop.name();
        }
    }
    if (ownGroup)
        set.endGroup();
    object->setProperty("dirty", NotDirty);
}

void EraObject::staticSaveTo(Settings &set, QObject *object, const bool &ownGroup, const bool &force)
{
    Q_ASSERT(object);
    if (force || object->property("dirty").toInt() == RamDirty) {
        const QMetaObject *superMeta = object->metaObject()->superClass();
        const QMetaObject *meta = object->metaObject();

        const QString &group = object->objectName().isEmpty() ? meta->className() : object->objectName();

        if (ownGroup)
            set.beginGroup(group);

        qCDebug(saveLog) << group;

        for (int i = superMeta->propertyOffset(); i < meta->propertyCount(); i++) {
            const QMetaProperty &prop = meta->property(i);
            if (prop.isUser()) {
                QMetaType::Type type = (QMetaType::Type)prop.type();
                switch (type) {
                case QMetaType::QDateTime:
                    set.setValue(prop.name(), prop.read(object).toDateTime().toString("yyyyMMddhhmmsszzz"));
                    break;
                case QMetaType::Float:
                case QMetaType::Double:
                    set.setValue(prop.name(), QString::number(prop.read(object).toDouble(), 'g', MAX_SAVED_DECIMALS));
                    break;
                case QMetaType::User: {
                    QObject *obj = prop.read(object).value<QObject *>();
                    Q_ASSERT_X(obj, "staticLoadFrom", "Custom class NOT known to QMetaType, register it with qmlRegisterType()!");

                    bool check = QMetaObject::invokeMethod(obj,
                                                           "saveTo",
                                                           Qt::DirectConnection,
                                                           Q_ARG(Settings &, set),
                                                           Q_ARG(bool, true),
                                                           Q_ARG(bool, force));
                    Q_ASSERT_X(check, "saveTo", "Could not invoke. Be sure you subclassed EraObject or defined method!: " + obj->objectName().toLatin1());
                    break;
                }
                default:
                    if (!prop.isConstant())
                        set.setValue(prop.name(), prop.read(object));
                }
            }
        }
        if (ownGroup)
            set.endGroup();
        object->setProperty("dirty", NotDirty);
        set.sync();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you add the definition of your `Settings` class ?

Comment: @Gwen, I added the definition in the updated section of the post

Comment: Can you also add `loadFrom` and `saveTo` definitions?

Comment: @Gwen done, I have added them its big but the saving is working, but loading is not working

Comment: No, I meant `Profile::loadFrom` and `Profile::saveTo`.

Comment: @Gwen Profile::loadFrom and Profile::saveTo they are overriden methods, they call the above methods in the edit

Comment: Can you also add `setOrReset`? Did you check if your `switch (type)` statement goes in the `default` case or the `string` case ?